# How to Count number of items in model using IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, model, ienumerable

I was wondering is it possible to do a counter for the number of items in a model, i know using list it is possible, but id prefer to use IEnumerable for the project purpose. it would be even better if it could be done in javascript for constant update but im not experienced enough in MVC and Javascript.

-Controller-

```
public class ModelController : Controller
{
    private JobData db = new JobData();

    //
    // GET: /Model/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var Model = db.Models.OrderByDescending(model => model.ModelType);
        int count = Model.Count();

        return View(Model.ToList());
    }
```

-View-

```
    @model IEnumerable<JobTracker.Models.Model>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Camera Models";
}

 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Table.js"></script>




<table id="tfhover" class="tftable" border="1">  
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelType)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {


    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModelType)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ModelID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ModelID }) 
          @*  @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ModelID })*@
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: you are using 'count' nowhere!!

Comment: Model.Count is within the controller method Index, however ive tried numerous other attempts but doesnt seem to work

Comment: I am asking that where you want to display the count. If you want it in action method, why don't you just use Model.ToList().Count(), because you are already converting Model to List before passing to view, right?

Comment: oh! yes i am putting it to a list! sorry about that, how should i go about displaying it on the view? sorry if it's a silly question, im still getting to grips with MVC and all its components

Comment: In your view also you can just use @Model.Count() to display count anywhere

Comment: Great..happy learning :)

Comment: if you want to convert your comment to an answer id be happy to confirm it and  upvote :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but your query is resolved so no need for it. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can just use `@Model.Count()` to display count anywhere –  (credit goes to @MukeshModhvadiya from the comment section)

Comment: this counts only the model not its references ie: inside a for loop.

Answer (score 3):

You are use Model.Count() inside View for MVC.  If you need it in javascript you can get this value in following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count ='@Model.Count()';
</script>
```

You have to write script in View file. separate js file this code not working. We are not able to access Model value in separate js file.